# Shadow is not visible on some UI elements

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, calayer, shadow

I have a helper method that helps me to add a shadow on all UI elements, and it works perfectly for the most of them, but on some of them, it doesn't.

For example, on this stackView below, there is no shadow when I run my app:

```
    var container = UIStackView()
    let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [button1, button2, button3])
            stackView.axis = .vertical
            stackView.distribution  = .equalSpacing
            stackView.alignment = .fill
            
            container = stackView
            self.view.addSubview(container)
            
            container.snp.makeConstraints { make in
                make.top.equalTo(view).offset(25)
                make.right.equalTo(view).offset(-25)
                make.width.equalTo(view.frame.width * 0.185)
                make.height.equalTo(view.frame.width * 0.65)
            }
            container.layer.addShadow()
```

I have also tried to call this `addShadow()` for my buttons(button1, button2, button3), but didn't work. 
I have tried different values in parameters of `addShadow()`, but...

Another example is where it *WORKS*, on my imageView:

```
let avatarImageView = UIImageView()
self.addSubview(avatarImageView)
        avatarImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        avatarImageView.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
        avatarImageView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.height.equalToSuperview()
            make.width.equalToSuperview().multipliedBy(0.5)
            make.left.equalToSuperview()
        }
        avatarImageView.layer.addShadow(opacity: 0.3, offsetWidth: 13, offsetHeight: 8)
```

Here is a shadow method(in extension of CALayer):

```
func addShadow(scale: Bool = true, opacity: Float = 0.4, offsetWidth: Int = 5, offsetHeight: Int = 5, radius: CGFloat = 5) {
        masksToBounds = false
        shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        shadowOpacity = opacity
        shadowOffset = CGSize(width: offsetWidth, height: offsetHeight)
        shadowRadius = radius
        shouldRasterize = true
        rasterizationScale = scale ? UIScreen.main.scale : 1
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

See Apple's [`UIStackView` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistackview).

> *Managing the Stack View’s Appearance:* 
> The UIStackView is a nonrendering subclass of UIView.

`UIStackView` just manages the position and size of its arranged views,  background or shadow won't show.